# Google API Key Invalid

Tags: google-api

My code keeps throwing an error "Please enter your Google API key", however I set it up.

```js
    google
      .search(querystring.stringify({ term: args.join("") }))
      .then(async response => {
        const title = await translate(response.title, "es");
        const snippet = await translate(response.snippet, "es");

        const embed = new RichEmbed()
          .setColor("0x00ff00")
          .setTitle(title)
          .setURL(response.formattedURL)
          .addField("Resultado de Google", snippet)
          .addField("Link", response.formattedURL);

        message.channel.startTyping();
        await delay(3000);

        message.channel
          .send(embed)
          .then(() => message.channel.stopTyping(true));
      });
```

Edit: Here are the variables:

```js
const Google = require('relevant-google');
const google = new Google('APIKEY');
const querystring = require('querystring');

// Don't worry about anything else tbh
```

Comment: First which api are you trying to access?  Second where are you adding the API key?  Please supply a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example this isnt enough code to test.    I need everything else.

Comment: DalmTo, I supplied enough information. The google api is clearly shows, and `const google = new Google('apikey')` is where the API key is. This is enough information.